# Hardware buttons problem. The panel with hardware buttons is missing

Tags: 12.04, command-line, wireless, camera, function-keys

I have problem with hardware buttons. I have MSI vr630x, but my panel with buttons for WiFi, camera and bluetooth are missing (it has been removed at all).

Is there a way to turn devices on? I have these devices working, I just don't have buttons to turn them on.

Answer (score 2):

For Wifi you can use NetworkManager or Wicd or KnetworkManager or other tool.

For Bluetooth you can use [blueman](http://blueman-project.org/):

> Blueman is a GTK+ Bluetooth Manager. Blueman is designed to be simple and intuitive for everyday bluetooth tasks such as:
>
> - Connecting to 3G/EDGE/GPRS via DUN profile.
> - Connecting to/Creating bluetooth networks
> - Connecting to input devices
> - Connecting to audio devices
> - Sending/Receiving/Browsing files via OBEX
> - Pairing

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

For camera you can use Cheese.

Great site on setting up your camera [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam).

Just search for a few tools and try them out, to see what you like the most.

Answer (score 2):

You can **enable** back your default indicator manually on your panel.

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run this command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```